# Unable to install zfs or zfsutils on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, software-installation, dependencies, zfs

I am unable to install ZFS on a recently upgraded install of Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04. I was hoping that the upgrade would resolve an issue with zfs I was having where neither `zpool` or `zfs` would run.

```
sudo apt install zfs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'zfsutils-linux' instead of 'zfs'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 zfsutils-linux : Depends: zfs-doc (= 0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16) but 0.6.5.9-1~trusty is to be installed
                  Depends: libnvpair1linux but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libuutil1linux but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libzfs2linux but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libzpool2linux but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: zfs-zed but it is not going to be installed
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried manually installing the dependencies listed and also an `apt clean` and `autoclean`.

the checkbox that says Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe) is checked in Software Updater

I would be grateful for any advice on how to debug this further and /or resolve it. I have found similar reports on SE and elsewhere but none of the suggestions worked for me.

I also tried 'Try downloading zfs-doc from here. All of the other packages seem to depend on it. You can install it by running dpkg -i ' but got the following errors:

```
 systemctl status zfs-mount.service
● zfs-mount.service - Mount ZFS filesystems
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/zfs-mount.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-05-28 11:49:35 BST; 1min 34s ago
  Process: 5358 ExecStart=/sbin/zfs mount -a (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 5358 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 28 11:49:35 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium systemd[1]: Starting Mount ZFS filesystems...
May 28 11:49:35 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium zfs[5358]: The ZFS modules are not loaded.
May 28 11:49:35 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium zfs[5358]: Try running '/sbin/modprobe zfs' as root to load them.
May 28 11:49:35 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium systemd[1]: zfs-mount.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 28 11:49:35 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium systemd[1]: Failed to start Mount ZFS filesystems.
May 28 11:49:35 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium systemd[1]: zfs-mount.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 28 11:49:35 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium systemd[1]: zfs-mount.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
codecowboy@codecowboy-P5E3-Premium:~/Downloads$ sudo sbin/modprobe zfs
sudo: sbin/modprobe: command not found
codecowboy@codecowboy-P5E3-Premium:~/Downloads$ sudo /sbin/modprobe zfs
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'zfs': Invalid argument
codecowboy@codecowboy-P5E3-Premium:~/Downloads$ sudo journalctl -xe
May 28 11:49:35 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium systemd[1]: zfs-mount.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 28 11:49:48 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium sudo[30638]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 28 11:50:01 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium cron[1029]: (*system*zfsutils-linux) RELOAD (/etc/cron.d/zfsutils-linux)
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium sudo[11155]: codecowboy : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/codecowboy/Downloads ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/modprobe z
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium sudo[11155]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by codecowboy(uid=0)
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: disagrees about version of symbol __cv_init
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: Unknown symbol __cv_init (err -22)
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: disagrees about version of symbol vn_close
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: Unknown symbol vn_close (err -22)
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: disagrees about version of symbol cv_timedwait_hires
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: Unknown symbol cv_timedwait_hires (err -22)
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: disagrees about version of symbol vn_seek
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: Unknown symbol vn_seek (err -22)
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: disagrees about version of symbol __cv_destroy
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: Unknown symbol __cv_destroy (err -22)
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: disagrees about version of symbol __cv_timedwait_sig
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: Unknown symbol __cv_timedwait_sig (err -22)
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: disagrees about version of symbol rootdir
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: Unknown symbol rootdir (err -22)
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: disagrees about version of symbol kobj_close_file
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: Unknown symbol kobj_close_file (err -22)
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: disagrees about version of symbol kobj_read_file
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: Unknown symbol kobj_read_file (err -22)
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: disagrees about version of symbol __kstat_delete
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: Unknown symbol __kstat_delete (err -22)
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: disagrees about version of symbol vn_open
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: Unknown symbol vn_open (err -22)
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: disagrees about version of symbol kobj_open_file
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: Unknown symbol kobj_open_file (err -22)
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: disagrees about version of symbol vn_getf
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: Unknown symbol vn_getf (err -22)
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: disagrees about version of symbol kobj_get_filesize
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: Unknown symbol kobj_get_filesize (err -22)
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: disagrees about version of symbol vn_fsync
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: Unknown symbol vn_fsync (err -22)
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: disagrees about version of symbol __cv_wait
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: Unknown symbol __cv_wait (err -22)
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: disagrees about version of symbol vn_getattr
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: Unknown symbol vn_getattr (err -22)
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: disagrees about version of symbol __cv_wait_sig
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: Unknown symbol __cv_wait_sig (err -22)
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: disagrees about version of symbol __kstat_install
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: Unknown symbol __kstat_install (err -22)
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: disagrees about version of symbol __cv_signal
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: Unknown symbol __cv_signal (err -22)
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: disagrees about version of symbol vn_rdwr
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: Unknown symbol vn_rdwr (err -22)
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: disagrees about version of symbol __cv_wait_io
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: Unknown symbol __cv_wait_io (err -22)
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: disagrees about version of symbol __kstat_create
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: Unknown symbol __kstat_create (err -22)
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: disagrees about version of symbol __cv_broadcast
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: Unknown symbol __cv_broadcast (err -22)
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: disagrees about version of symbol vn_openat
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: Unknown symbol vn_openat (err -22)
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: disagrees about version of symbol __kstat_set_raw_ops
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium kernel: zfs: Unknown symbol __kstat_set_raw_ops (err -22)
May 28 11:51:38 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium sudo[11155]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 28 11:52:00 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium sudo[11159]: codecowboy : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/codecowboy/Downloads ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl 
May 28 11:52:00 codecowboy-P5E3-Premium sudo[11159]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by codecowboy(uid=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error after upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04:

```
 zfsutils-linux : Depends: zfs-doc (= 0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16) but 0.6.5.9-1~trusty is to be installed
```

1. I did `apt-get remove zfs-doc` which removed all related zfs dependencies (all of which were 0.6.5.9-1~trusty).
2. After this `apt-get install zfsutils-linux` worked, but after rebooting the zfs module wouldn't install (dmsg showed symbol resolution errors loading zfs module *zfs: disagrees about version of symbol __cv_init*)
3. The final step was remove the obsolete spl module from dkms `dkms remove spl/0.6.5.9 -all` then reboot. My zfs volume was automatically mounted again.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `Software and Updates` settings (Search for `Software and Updates` in the Dash).

Make sure the checkbox that says `Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)` is checked.

Run `sudo apt update` to add all of the extra packages to your system.

Try and install `zfs` again.

Comment: Try downloading `zfs-doc` from [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/all/zfs-doc/download). All of the other packages seem to depend on it. You can install it by running `dpkg -i <file you just downloaded>`

Comment: thanks. I tried that and got a little further but now getting new errors which I have added to the question

Comment: What errors are you getting now?

Comment: I've added the errors to the question. I'm now back to where I was before upgrading - "The ZFS modules are not loaded.
Try running '/sbin/modprobe zfs' as root to load them." But running that command doesn't work - "modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'zfs': Invalid argument"

Comment: Does this help: https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/3922

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59455/discussion-between-codecowboy-and-yamboy1).